# Getting 406(not acceptable error) in vuejs, vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authorization, vuex, bearer-token

I am working on a project and I am getting 406(not acceptable) error in the browser. I am using vuejs, vuex framework.
verify.vue code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <usernav/>
    <div class="container">
    <h1 style="padding:90px;"> Enter OTP</h1>
    <div>
      <mdb-input label="OTP" v-model="value" />
      <br />
      <mdb-btn color="info" @click="verify()">Verify</mdb-btn>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbInput, mdbBtn } from 'mdbvue'
import usernav from './user_nav'
export default {
  name: 'otp',
  components: {
    mdbInput,
    mdbBtn,
    usernav
  },
  data () {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    verify () {
      this.$store.dispatch('VERIFY', {
        otp: this.value
      }).then(success => {
        console.log('success')
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

The verify.js code:

```js
import { isAuthenticated } from './auth'
import axios from 'axios'

export default ({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
    VERIFY: (payload) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const userId = isAuthenticated().user._id
        const token = isAuthenticated().token
        console.log(userId)
        console.log(token)
        axios
          .post(`https://onu-backend.herokuapp.com/api/onu/user/${userId}/verifyEmail`, payload, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            }
          }).then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              console.log(response)
              resolve(true)
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            reject(error)
          })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

The isAuthenticated code:

```js
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
  }
  return false
}
```

Error I am getting: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqWrz.png)

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error? The api used in the code is cross checked with postman and is working fine. I think there some problem with sending bearer token. Please help.

Comment: read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406 ... `I think there some problem with sending bearer token` no, since that has nothing to do with the error returned

Comment: by the way ... using axios inside a "new Promise" is an anti-pattern (not a cause for error though) ... since axios is promise based, there's no need to wrap it in a Promise constructor

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah I will change that part... but so far is the code I have written correct

Comment: Well, the server doesn't like it .... but, there's no server code, so ....

Comment: `The isAuthenticated code:` you do realise you'll throw an error in `VERIFY` - since `false` doesn't have a property called ... well, anything, so `.user._id` will throw - not sure if you can use `isAuthenticated()?.user?._id` syntax yet